snap_daemon and snapd-range-******-root users appeared out of nowhere after upgrade to ubuntu 24.04
After upgrading to Ubuntu 24.04 two extra users appeared on my login screen: snap_daemon and snapd-range-524288-root
It seems like this is an error of sorts and they are not supposed to be there.
My "Settings" is very slow to open, System->Users shows some error and almost crashes, so I can't remove them from here. I also fear that snap will break if I remove them using userdel from the terminal.
Do you know if it is safe to remove those users?



It turns out that polkitd failed to upgrade properly and this caused a lot of other issues (Settings app lagged because of that).
I fixed this issue by:

adding a group and a user for polkitd as this post suggest:


My solution was adding one line to /etc/group, in terminal "sudo vi
/etc/group":
polkitd:x:997:
and one line to /etc/passwd, in terminal "sudo vi /etc/passwd":
polkitd:x:997:997:polkit:/nonexistent:/usr/sbin/nologin


running sudo apt --fix-broken install

rebooting


